# Passing parameter and refresh frame

Tags: c#, parameters, uwp

So far i have 2 frames called Login Form and Main Form.
After press Login button i want to pass User ID from Login Form to Main Form and use it to set text for a text block. So far i have code like this

**Login Form**

```java
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    String id = txtID.Text;
                    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), id);
                    Window.Current.Close();
                }
```

**Main Form**

```java
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Parameter != null)
                    {
                        idFromLogin = e.Parameter.ToString();
                        loginInfor.Visibility = Visibility;
                        username.Text = idFromLogin;
                   }
                   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                }
```

i want username text appear and value is from Login Form when user login successfully but when i do this,the text block appear first without nothing and after login it didn't show up with the text from Login Form although

Main Form received User ID from Login Form. 

Help me please.Thanks

Comment: can you explain little more.. There are two page MainPage and LoginPage.when you click  login button on main page it will open Login Page, Right ? and you want to pass entered UserID in LoginPage to MainPage TextBlock but you are still in LoginPage

Comment: Yes i 've pass UserID from loginPage to Mainpage successfully but when i use it to set text for TextBlock immediately after the Login Page closed but it didn't work. I've checked it in console to make sure if it passed. The previous comment is my mistake. sorry

Comment: okay thanks for elaboration

Comment: everything is looking fine https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlsWJhYaBXFrefWY88zr3OZM5TQ

Answer (score 1):

problem is

```
Window.Current.Close();
```

you are closing LoginPage without setting Value in MainPage just remove this line it is working fine in my end.

Comment: You got me wrong, First frame of mine is mainpage then user click Login button. The login form show up. After Login the textblock's text from main page received ID from Login Page and set text after it. But when i did it, Main Page still received ID but textblock.text isn't working, i guess maybe it didn't update UI

Comment: Okay i am Checking and updating answer ;)

Comment: Yeah it's working but it open a new frame, the problem is i want to close the login form after login success and Current mainPage is updated not open a new Page

Comment: UWP apps typically use a single Window instance, you do not need to close the window when you navigate between pages. What you understanding is incorrect.